# c# com server, interface registration or late binding, both failed

Tags: c#, interface, com, interop, autocad

I have this com interface:

```
namespace BuildingApp_Client
{
[Guid("5B5B731C-B37A-4aa2-8E50-42192BD51B17")]
public interface iComObject
{
    void Test();
}

[ClassInterface( ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(iComObject))]
[ProgId("BuildingApp_Client.ComObject")]
[Guid("44D8782B-3F60-4cae-B14D-FA060E8A4D01")]
public class ComObject: MarshalByRefObject, iComObject
{
    public ComObject()
    {

    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Test()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ComTest");
    }
}
}
```

target framework is 4.7.2,
Configuration: Active(Debug)
Platform: Active(AnyCpu)
platform target: X64
Register for com interop ticked.

First I thought Autodispatch is for late binding and may not need registration, so I tried to obtain com object from AcadApplication.GetInterfaceObject("BuildingApp_Client.ComObject") which failed.

Then I tried to register it using regasm (from directory C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319) which resulted in
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'E:\ProgramingProjects\BuildingApp_Client.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:

modified as simoon said in first comment, now the class and interface are [ComVisible] and no more [comdefaultinterface] and no more descendant of marshalbyrefobject.

I receive the following internal expression, it if helps:
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnTypeCustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.

Comment: try to 1. remove MarshalByRefObject 2. put ComVisible(true) on class and interface, not method. 3. remove ComDefaultInterface. Or post a reproducing project somewhere.